# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 network controller driver conflict?

Tags: 10.10, networking, drivers, dual-boot, windows-7

Has anyone had problems with how Windows and Linux drivers configure the network card? I have a Realtek 8112L LAN Controller and am dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10. After using network processes under both systems the network card stops working under either, forcing me to reset the CMOS.

**Update** The CMOS reset works but is not necessary for me. Shutting down and unplugging the power cord works as well.

I fear the only solution will be for someone to fix the driver, if anyone has another idea I would love to hear it.

Comment: Would you explain this futher, if this is still a problem? You say after using network processes.. Does that mean network card stops working in both windows and Ubuntu at times after working some time ? In that case it may be a hardware fault.

Comment: @Jamess
Yes, it's still a problem. It's not a hardware failure though otherwise there would be intermittent outages and I can reproduce the problem by running linux and then windows. I think hieukieng is right, linux loads a file to the network card that is incompatible with windows drivers. I would like to know if there are any fixes though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it works well on Ubuntu 10.10 but Win 7 cannot recognize the card. The solution is to cold reboot and wait for a few minutes then turn on and boot into Win 7 ( I googled somewhere but now I forgot). According to some explanation, Ubuntu loads some kind of firmware into the card that Win 7 cannot recognize. Anyway, it worked for me.

Comment: I'll give it a try, that would be easier than moving pins on the motherboard, I would still like a better fix.

Comment: Cold reboot didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually, if I shut down and unplug the power cord it does the trick, that's probably what you meant by cold reboot :)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem.  Windows 7 ethernet not working, was previously working prior to installing Ubuntu as dual boot.  Ethernet works well in Ubuntu. 
The solution is simple.  Totally unplug power cord, wait a few minutes, boot into Windows.  Problem will be gone!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this does work. However, it's still not a satisfactory solution given that I will need to do this each time I switch OSs